# TempData + Windows Authentication = No timeout. Is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, timeout, windows-authentication, tempdata

My MVC application is running under Windows Authentication.

I have used TempData at various places in my application. The problem is that, they get clear with session timeout. however, the Windows login is still running. How can I set them to remain intact until the user logs off his windows login.. I mean, there shouldn't be any timeout as such. is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO my understand, TempData only gets persist it's value till the next action, which is why it's called "Temp"Data. And a session will be only be able to maintain the data for current user session.

If you don't want timeout(which sounds really weird to me and i can smell bad code practice) then use Cache or persist data to database. You can keep the data as long as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can change session timeout value in the web config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
```

Just change the minutes timeout value from 20 minutes to a higher value

e.g for 2 days:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2880"/>
```

Comment: any other option? i want it to be unlimited if possible

Comment: I think you can set it high - a year for example - but it's probably not a good idea. You could look at using a persistent cookie rather than session.

Comment: not really, i have set it to 2880 and still it timesout in quite a lesser time.

Comment: perhaps IIS is recycling the app pool if you're getting regular timeouts. You could use Out of proc session state if you want to persist your session data - e.g. make your sessionstate mode = sqlserver or stateserver